# CString Tokenization Issue

Tags: c++, mfc, tokenize

I'm using `CString::Tokenize` method in order to tokenize a string using a delimiter, but I noticed something strange, I call that method on my string inside a loop because I want to retrieve all the tokens inside the string, here's my code:

```
CString strToken;
for(int nTokenPos = 0; nTokenPos < dialog->myValue.GetLength(); nTokenPos++)
{
   //TRACE( "The Size of the string is %d\n", dialog->myValue.GetLength());
   TRACE( "Iteration No %d\n",nTokenPos);
   strToken = dialog->myValue.Tokenize(_T("X"), nTokenPos);
   strToken+="\n";
   OutputDebugString(strToken);
}
```

note:`dialog->myValue` is the string that I want to tokenize. When I test that code on '99X1596' (for example) the output is:

```
Iteration No 0
99
Iteration No 4
596
```

another example: '4568X6547'
output:

```
Iteration No 0
4568
Iteration No 6
547
```

I don't know why it ignores the first character after the delimiter 'X' also it skips one iteration!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You increase `nTokenPos` in the `for` loop. That's why second token is broken. `CString::Tokenize` updates `nTokenPos` and uses it in following iterations.

Correct usage is like this:

```
CString str = "99X1596";
int curPos = 0;
CString resToken = str.Tokenize(_T("X"), curPos);
while(!resToken.IsEmpty())
{
   // Process resToken here - print, store etc
   OutputDebugString(resToken);

   // Obtain next token
   resToken = str.Tokenize(_T("X"), curPos);
}
```

Comment: i increment it because i want to retrieve all the tokens in the string

Comment: You don't need it, `Tokenize` will increment it for you. See updated answer for example.

Comment: @Eslam No. Just put the output **at the first line** of `while` body. See updated example